# Remove spacing in CollectionView iOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate to make it square but strange spacing is showing at the end.

[image]
[image]

> My Code

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if collectionView == self.bannerClcView {

        let cellSize = CGSize.init(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        return cellSize

    }else if collectionView == self.category {

        let cellSize = CGSize.init(width: (self.category.frame.size.width/3), height: category.frame.size.width/3)
        return cellSize

    }else {

        let cellSize = CGSize.init(width: (recomended_Ads_Clc.frame.size.width/2), height: 220)
        return cellSize

    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

How can I remove the spacing? Please help.

Comment: Do you want to stretch your cells? or move them to the middle?

Comment: You might check if the right-side AutoLayout constraint for your `UICollectionView` is attached to the 'safe-area'. Seems like you'd rather it be attached to the superview.

Comment: cell should cover full size of CollectionView , in first , i want 3 cell only covering whole width , yes i want to stretch the cell , it should be equal to the exactly collectionView.width/3 . @RaziTiwana

Comment: @hgwhittle , oh i think this issue , working fine on iphone 8 , can you please tell me how to remove constraint from  `safe-area` ?

Comment: try this. 10 is the gap between two cell in my case....  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width/2)-10 , height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

Comment: also set collectionView View Content Mode to Scale To Fill.

Comment: @Dhiru did you lay out your collection view using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

If you open your Storyboard where you've laid out your `UICollectionView` and select its trailing constraint, I image you'll see something like this in the Attributes inspector:

[image]

You'll need to uncheck "Relative to margin" to remove the extra space you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is with the source view that you compute the width property for the cell inside the function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

instead of

`let cellSize = CGSize.init(width: (recomended_Ads_Clc.frame.size.width/2), height: 220)
return cellSize`

write `return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 2) - 10, height: 220)`

And compute the height as you want. 10 will be the space between the cells